# How can I reload the data in a WatchKit tableview?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

I have an app for iPhone with a Tableview, whose data comes from CoreData.

[image]

The same data are also displayed in a watch app:

[image]

If I add a row from the iPhone app:

[image]

and I reload data in the Watch app:

[image]

I see the old rows empty!

[image]

If the stop the watch app and I start it again, everything appears correctly!

[image]

This is the code to fill the Tableview in the watch app

```
-(void)awakeWithContext:(id)context{
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
       [self loadTable];
}

-(void)loadTable{
    NSLog(@"loadTableData");
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Data"];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Data"
        inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortedDateAndTime" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortByDate, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    self.watchMArray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

  //  [self.watchTableView setRowTypes:self.watchMArray];
    [self.watchTableView setNumberOfRows:self.watchMArray.count withRowType:@"data"];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.watchMArray.count; i++)
    {
        WatchTableCell *cell = [self.watchTableView rowControllerAtIndex:i];
        NSManagedObject *data = [self.watchMArray objectAtIndex:i];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
            //Background Thread
            UIImage *foto =[self loadImageFromData:[data valueForKey:@"imageData"]];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                //Run UI Updates
            [cell.watchImage setImage:foto];
            [cell.watchDate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [data valueForKey:@"dataEOra"] ]];
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This is the code I am currently using to reload it:

```
- (IBAction)reloadTable {        
    [self loadTable];
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell. I'd want to run through that code in LLDB, which would almost certainly be useful.

Comment: since WatchOS2.0 released, may I know how do you manage to do the same thing (coredata across iOS and watchOS data consistency) now?

Comment: With watchOS 2 coredata is a big big problem !!

Comment: @Ragazzetto yes, I have been thinking of the solutions and none of them is perfect to make the data consistent on watchOS2.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the link @leolobato posted, there is actually a workaround. It did solve my problem.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1098875#1098875

> when you change your rows just set them to =@"" first.
>
> For example, if your row has a row.Label and you are changing it, do row.Label.text = @"" then again right after row.Label.text =@"[Actual text]"

Comment: It's your post led me to this post and solved my problem, so thank you :)

Comment: This is a good workaround that works, this was driving me crazy for hours. Seems to be a bug in the Beta which they'll fix hopefully.

Comment: Has this bug been fixed in the GM version?

Answer (score 6):

Calling the `setRowTypes:` or `setNumberOfRows:withRowType:` method.

Below is a statement from the developer document, I believe this will work.

> When you want to update the contents of a table, call setRowTypes: or
>   setNumberOfRows:withRowType: again with the new row type information.
>   Calling these methods again forces the table to discard the old rows
>   and create new ones. To insert new rows without removing the old ones,
>   use the insertRowsAtIndexes:withRowType: method.

[Link to document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceTable_class/index.html)

Comment: as you can see from the code in the method loadTable there is already a method call [self.watchTableView setNumberOfRows: self.watchMArray.count withRowType: @ "date"];

Comment: Technically it should work with only single line of code, mentioning the setRowTypes. I haven't tried, but I have read the document, thats why I send you.

Comment: Thank you @JayahariV , I've use the Duncan code but in my case the change of the code has not solved the problem !! Now all rows are empty :-(

Comment: Is this still a bug in the current version after beta?  I log what text I'm using in the labels when I do a reload, but its not changing what is in the table.

Answer (score 4):

I've discovered that calling setNumberOfRows:rowType does not refresh the table unless you call it from the willActivate method. I had a delegate method that I was calling from a modal controller which would fetch a new set of records from the parent app and then reload the table. Even though printing out numberOfRows showed the new number of rows that I set, visually the existing rows were still displayed on screen. It was only after I set a flag in my delegate method and then in willActivate checked that flag and only then reloaded the table, did it refresh the display.

Comment: This is actually documented in the `WKInterfaceController` docs.

Answer (score 1):

To reload the data, change your IBAction to:

```
- (IBAction)reloadTable {
    [self.watchTableView setNumberOfRows:self.watchMArray.count withRowType:@"data"];
}
```

From [Apple's developer documentation on WKInterfaceTable](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceTable_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014965-CH1-SW13):

> This method removes any existing rows from the table and configures a new set of rows based on the information in the numberOfRows and rowType parameters.

Given you are using `setNumberOfRows:withRowType:` in your original code, I have used that here. The method `setRowTypes:` also achieves the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Duncan, but in my case the change of the code has not solved the problem !!
Now all rows are empty:-(

Comment: Yeah ;-) The strange thing is that the detailview works perfectly, only the data of the table are missing :-(

Comment: Small update, is displayed in the table only the last item in that array

Comment: I'll add that I am seeing some strange behavior with watchkit tables. I am calling setNumberOfRows:withRowType using an NSTimer and the reloaded table is not rendering correctly. The row label text is coming from the nib and not my code. So it could be watchkit code and not yours.

Comment: Are you using an NSTimer to poll for changes in your underlying dataset?

Comment: no NSTimer @DuncanBabbage ! I manually update the table in watch extension after I added the object in the iPhone App !

Comment: The strange thing is that if I put a NSLog to see the table data in console would seem that everything is right !  [cell.watchImage setImage:foto];
                    NSLog(@"immagine %@",cell.watchImage); 2015-01-24 11:20:56.196 WatchKit Extension[9555:291876] immagine <WKInterfaceImage: 0x7fee40c34c70>

Comment: @jkingyens so do you think is a WatchKit bug ?

Comment: @Ragazzetto I think it's likely there are still bugs in the SDK, yes.

Answer (score 1):

For watchOS 5.1, iOS 12.1 it only worked if I added the `setNumberOfRows:withRowType:` in `didAppear` method.
Using the `awake(withContext:)` or `willActivate` did not work for me. The first 4 rows were blank.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe  you have to do two things simultaneously  in order to achieve same result of tableview.reloadData() iOS function , so to reload a table in the watch with newly data do the following :
1-call table method :setNumberOfRows
2-loop through the rows  refreshing values .

```
vacationList.setNumberOfRows(dict.count, withRowType: "vacationRow")
    for index in 0..<vacationList.numberOfRows {
        if let controller = vacationList.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as? VacationRowcontroller {
            controller.vacation = dict.objectForKey("\(index)") as? NSDictionary
        }
    }
```

hint : dict = dictionary of newly reloaded data from backend.